# Rocket's State errors with "Attempted to retrieve unmanaged state" when using an explicit lifetime?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

When using Rocket's `State` with omitted lifetimes then a request to the route is handled ok:

```
#[post("/foo")]
pub fn foo_handler(db: State<Db>) {
    // ...
}
```

However, if explicit lifetimes are provided then Rocket errors on requests with `Attempted to retrieve unmanaged state!`:

```
#[post("/foo")]
pub fn foo_handler<'a>(db: State<&'a Db>) {
    // ...
}
```

There's either something the compiler isn't picking up here or Rocket avoids a safety check, as this compiles ok without any error or warnings. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think those are the same signature. What does `db: State<&'static Db>` do?

Comment: Nope, still the same error and compiles without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the way to achieve the required result:

```
#[post("/foo")]
pub fn foo_handler<'a>(db: State<'a, Db>) {
  // ...
}
```

A example helped in Rocket's [State](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/struct.State.html) docs. I'd expect an error to be thrown for the above implementations though, as it's valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I found this error resulted from failing to call `unwrap()` on the value I was initializing to be used in the `State`.

```
let index = load().unwrap(); // <-- without unwrap, compiled but failed on request
rocket::ignite()
  .manage(index) // normal mount and so on here
... etc ...
```